Material UI Collapse / React-Spring transition bug ( When Expanding / Collapsing - Whole page scrolls )
I been facing this bug for some time now, the issue is when collapsing/expanding with the Mui Collapse transition, the whole browser page scrolls when the animation happens:
https://imgur.com/a/NPvhdHb
This is my code for Mui Collapse:
<Collapse in={overTitle}>

    <Box
        sx={{
            // color: "#FFC121",
            color: "#FFF",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontWeight: 600,
            paddingBottom: "20px",
            marginRight: "40px",
        }}
    >
    
        {"Subtitle Text Here"}
    
    </Box>


</Collapse>

This is my code using react-spring:
// React Spring
const [measureRef, { height }] = useMeasure();

const collapse_styles = useSpring({
    config: config.stiff,
    from: {
        height: 0
    },
    to: {
        height: overTitle ? height : 0
    }
});


<animated.div style={{ overflow: "hidden", ...styles }}>

        <div
          ref={measureRef}
        >
        
          {"Subtitle Text Here"}
          
        </div>
        
</animated.div>

both are simple examples yet both face the same scrolling issue,
can anyone explain why this is happening? is this a known bug?

I think this is a styling issue. When you expand the collapse, the height of the background increases, and the collapse content pushes down. You might be able to fix this issue by setting the collapse component's position to absolute.
